# Creating a Sqlite table with dynamically generated fields

Tags: ruby, sqlite

### I'm using the sqlite3 gem in ruby, and here is the example the gems github gives:

```
require "sqlite3"

# Open a database
db = SQLite3::Database.new "test.db"

# Create a table
rows = db.execute <<-SQL
  create table numbers (
    name varchar(30),
    val int
  );
SQL
```

#### here is my implementation where I try to replace the argument of db.execute with a dynamically generated string

```
require "sqlite3"

db_params = {
    db_name: "house-reps", 
    tables: 
        [
            {
                table_name: "house-reps-party",
                table_fields: [
                    "region varchar(30)",
                    "congress int",
                    "year int",
                    "party varchar(30)",
                    "percent int",
                    "seats int"
                ]
            }
        ]
}
def init_db(db_params)
    tables = db_params[:tables]

    db = SQLite3::Database.new "#{db_params[:db_name]}"
    tables.each do |table|
        db.execute("<<-SQL\n  create table #{table[:table_name]} (\n   #{table[:table_fields].join(",\n    ")}\n   );\nSQL")
    end
end

init_db(db_params)
```

#### Here is the output of the string interpolation:

```
<<-SQL
  create table party-total (
   region varchar(30),
    congress int,
    year int,
    party varchar(30),
    percent int,
    seats int
   );
SQL
```

#### But when I run the program it gives me this:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize': near "<<": syntax error (SQLite3::SQLException)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in `execute'
    from database.rb:25:in `block in init_db'
    from database.rb:23:in `each'
    from database.rb:23:in `init_db'
    from database.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

#### I'm guessing it has to do with how db.execute is called. i've tried it these ways:

```
db.execute("<<-SQL\n  create table #{table[:table_name]} (\n   #{table[:table_fields].join(",\n    ")}\n   );\nSQL")

db.execute "<<-SQL\n  create table #{table[:table_name]} (\n   #{table[:table_fields].join(",\n    ")}\n   );\nSQL"

db.execute <<-SQL "\n  create table #{table[:table_name]} (\n   #{table[:table_fields].join(",\n    ")}\n   );\n" SQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the

```
<<-SQL
SQL
```

These are not part of the string but "quotes" for a multiline string.

Both of these strings have the content `hello`

```
"hello"

<<-SQL
hello
SQL
```